# RegularExpressionValidator returning false for a valid input

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, c#-4.0

I want to validate input into a textbox, so it must contain six (optionally seven) characters within square brackets. This can appear anywhere within the string, not the entire string itself. Example valid input: `Hello World [XX1111]`

I have come up with the following Regular Expression: `\[.......?\]`

However, this expression does not seem to work within a `RegularExpressionValidator`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rfvTest" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTest" 
    ValidationExpression="\[.......?\]" ErrorMessage="Enter in the right format...">Enter in the right format</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="test" />
```

Even valid input, causes the error to display, and the `.IsValid` property of the `Page` to be false.

Interestingly, the following C# code will cause `match` to be `true` (with text of `Hello [XX1111]`)

```
            Regex r = new Regex(rfvTest.ValidationExpression);
            bool match = r.IsMatch(txtTest.Text);
```

So: What's up here. I believe the expression itself to be correct, it validates as expected using the `Regex` class, but the `RegularExpressionValidator` will not validate the input.

Comment: What if you enter only the text matched by the regex (ie, `[xxxxxxx]`)?

Comment: I guess you need to double escape the backslashes in the XML file.

Comment: What about..`\[.?.{6,}\]`?

Comment: @fge Yes- That validates! So does it automatically assume word boundaries then? I guess the answer is a `.*` before and after, then...

Comment: @bgs264 it was a wild guess... And it sucks, really (and not word boundaries, no -- automatic anchors at the beginning and end)

Comment: @VishalSuthar there are no upper bounds in your `{}` quantifier, so that won't fit. But it looks like the problem is elsewhere...

Comment: @fge Thanks, want to write that as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @fge Yes, that's what I meant ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that this control unfortunately adds beginning and end of input anchors to the regular expression you submit (and does not document that it does so)...

Which means you must surround your regex with, yes, `.*` on both sides. Could be viewed as a bug...